# The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/session timed out after 30 seconds

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, appium

I am trying to run automation in mobile from desktop. I am getting timeout exception while running automation in mobile. I have disabled firewall also. Is anybody can help me here. Even, I increased time out to 3 minutes but also doesn't help me.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.SetCapability("device", "Android");
capabilities.SetCapability("browserName", "chrome");
capabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "Motorola Moto g");
capabilities.SetCapability("platformName", "Android");
capabilities.SetCapability("platformVersion", "7.0");

driver = new AndroidDriver<IWebElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.facebook.com");
```

Comment: Are you sure your appium server with default settings? Because that seems a requirement if I skim through this manual: http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/appium-tutorial-for-beginners/ You could verify if you have anything listening on port 4723 by running `netstat -a | findstr 4723`. If that doesn't return any results, fix that. Your code looks fine.

Comment: Use `telnet localhost 4723` to make sure server is running and responding to requests

Comment: @rene I executed the netstat -a | findstr 4723 command and the following result: TCP    127.0.0.1:4723         Mahi-PC:0              LISTENING

Comment: can you post the error that you get? it makes it easy to undestand.

Comment: Issue is resolved now, I removed the timeout so it is working fine now